# Pyes: Selective assignment of Object Type to JSON

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I was trying to understand and to work through some example usages of PyES with elastic search when I found this snippet on Object Type:  http://packages.python.org/pyes/guide/reference/mapping/object-type.html

In the example JSON:

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "person" : {
            "name" : {
                "first_name" : "Shay",
                "last_name" : "Banon"
            },
            "sid" : "12345"
        },
        "message" : "This is a tweet!"
    }
}
```

"tweet", "person" and "name" are all dicitonaries.  **Why is it in his example mapping of the object type, he doesn't add `"type": "object"` to the `"name"` or `"tweet"` dictionary, as shown below**:

```
{
    "tweet" : {
        "properties" : {
            "person" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "name" : {
                        "properties" : {
                            "first_name" : {"type" : "string"},
                            "last_name" : {"type" : "string"}
                        }
                    },
                    "sid" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
                }
            }
            "message" : {"type" : "string"}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paragraph under the example states: "In order to mark a mapping of type object, set the type to object. This is an optional step, since if there are properties defined for it, it will automatically be identified as an object mapping." So, I think the example just demonstrates that `"type" : "object"` is optional.